# Solving a Linear Mean Square Estimation the Easy Way

Tags: estimation, self-study, least-squares

I have an exercise which is quite trivial. However I got stuck and I'm not sure if this the end-result. I assume there has to be a way to get this result much quicker.

Given are two randomly distributed variables y and n with mean 0 and variance 1. Further we know that $E\{yn\} = 0.5$ We measure $$x=y+n$$

We look for linear-mean-square estimation of y as a function of x.

From the given facts we now x has zero mean two. The variance has to be $$var(x) = var(y)+var(n)+2\cdot cov(yn)$$
because y and n are correlated. Therefor $var(x)$ becomes $$1+1+2\cdot 0.5 = 3$$

y becomes $y = n-x$ and $\hat{y}$ should have the form $\hat{y}= ax+b$.
For a and b I already have the general formula:
$$a=\frac{E\{xy\}-m_xm_y}{\sigma_x^2}$$
$$b=\frac{E\{x^2\}m_y-E\{xy\}m_x}{\sigma_x^2}.$$
In my case y should be $n-x$ if i got this right. But solving the problem with those formulas for a and b leaves me with terms like $E\{xn\}$. How can I know what this mean should be? I can't assume they are uncorrelated, can I? Probably I'm running completely in the wrong direction, and the solution is much more obvious.

EDIT 1: From Fat32's input I get for a:
$$a = \frac{E\{x(n-x)\}}{\sigma_x^2}=\frac{3-1.5}{3}=1/2$$
and b $$b=\frac{E\{x^2\}m_y-E\{x(n-x)\}m_x}{\sigma_x^2}=\frac{3-1.5}{3}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
The solution would therefor be $y=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(1-x)$ Not sure if this is true. Have to test it with random samples.

EDIT 2:
I did a test with matlab:

```
N = 10000;             %// Number of samples in each vector
M = randn(N, 2);

R = [1 0.5; 0.5 1]; %// correlation matrix
M = M * chol(R); %used to calculated depended random variables

n = M(:, 1);
y = M(:, 2);

x = y+n;

y_hat = -0.5*x+0.5;

mean(y-y_hat)
```

y_hat is not even close to the real y. Has not even the same mean. I don't get it. I'm making definitely some mistakes here.

EDIT 3:
Found another formula which uses the a and b. Inserted the linear leas squares solution becomes $$\hat{y}=\rho_{xy}\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}(x-m_x)+m_y.$$ When I insert my values I get:
$$\hat{y}=\rho_{xy}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x.$$
Rho is $\frac{1.5}{\sqrt(3)}$ and so $\hat{y}$ becomes 0.5x as @Fat32 pointed out. The error above was that b is zero because $m_x$ and $m_y$ are zero.

Comment: Hey, for computing $a$ (and also $b$) you should have $E\{x(n-x)\} = 1.5-3 = -1.5$ ? why do you take $E\{xn\} = 1$ despite my answer says $1.5$ ?

Comment: @Fat32 sorry I worked quite sloppy. Too much learning for today.

Comment: You are solving those $a$ and $b$ somehow wrong. I solved it with the same parameters to be $a = 0.5$ and $b = 0$ and it yields the expected result...

Comment: @Fat32 hm? Got this once too. So there is an error in my calculations. Strange is, I've just posted an update which leads to the perfect solution. However this solution is not 0.5x...

Comment: I will put the answer...

Comment: Thats it! You just have to try it often enough... the correct rho times 1/sqrt(3) is your 0.5. But since I've tested with 1000 samples this was not always the best solution. You got it! thanks!

Comment: No, it's not about sample size. Just see the answer please.

Comment: No I meant when trying to prove this with matlab with a small sample size, it can happen that another solution might result in a smaller error. But if you run the script many times, 0.5x will be the least square solution.

Comment: yes that's right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I wanted to show you how to get those minimum linear mean square estimator coefficients $a$ and $b$ for your given problem setup. The procedure is summarised from the book Statistical Digital Signal Processing_MonsonHayes.

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, we observe $X$ and want to estimate $Y$ using a linear estimator :

$$ \hat{Y} = a\cdot X + b $$

which minimized the mean square error $$\xi^2 = E\{ (Y-\hat{Y})^2 \} $$.

The solution is:

$$\boxed{ a = \frac{ E\{XY\} - m_xm_y }{ \sigma_x^2} } $$

$$\boxed{ b = \frac{ E\{X^2\} m_y - E\{X Y\} m_x }{ \sigma_x^2} } $$

And a better simplification happens by recognizing the **correlation coefficient** $$\rho_{xy} = \frac{ E\{XY\} - m_xm_y }{ \sigma_x \sigma_y } $$

Then the optimal linear estimator of $Y$ is re-written as:

$$\boxed{ \hat{Y} = \rho_{xy} \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}(X-m_x) + m_y }$$

Note that the resulting mimimum mean square error is also given by :

$$ \xi_o^2 = \sigma_y^2(1-\rho_{xy}^2) $$

And further note that the orthogonality principle, for the optimum estimator, requires that:

$$ E\{X\cdot E\} = E\{ X (Y - \hat{Y}) \} = 0 $$.

Now coming to your problem,

We are given the observation $ X = Y + N $ with the following statistics:

$$ E\{Y\}= E\{N\} = E\{X\} = 0 ~~~,~~~ \sigma_y^2 = 1, \sigma_n^2 = 1, \sigma_x^2 = 3$$

(you can compute $\sigma_x^2 = 3$ from the givens) and further given $E\{YN\} = 0.5$. Now we shall compute $\rho_{xy}$ which is:

$$\rho_{xy} = \frac{ E\{XY\} - m_x m_y }{ \sigma_x \sigma_y } = \frac{ E\{(Y+N)Y\}\}-0\cdot 0 }{ \sqrt{3}  } = \frac{ 1 + 1.5}{ \sqrt{3} }  = \frac{ \sqrt{3} }{2}$$

Then the optimal linear mse becomes:

$$ \hat{Y} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{3}}(X-0) + 0  = 0.5 X $$

From which you can also infer that $a = 0.5$ and $b=0$.

Note that you could also reach the same result by just computing $a$ and $b$ according to formulas as follows:

$$ a = \frac{ E\{XY\} - m_xm_y }{ \sigma_x^2} = \frac{ 1.5 - 0 \cdot 0 }{3} = 0.5$$

$$ b = \frac{ E\{X^2\} m_y - E\{X Y\} m_x }{ \sigma_x^2} = \frac{ 3 \cdot 0  - 1.5 \cdot 0 }{ 3}  = 0$$

pretty simple ?

Comment: That's the book I got it from. Finally got it right. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that you could also use very simply the direct equation for $a$ and $b$ but magically you messed up :-))

Comment: Yeah :D Mentioned the errors in the last edit. The problem when learning advanced stuff for the finals is that you get stuck on simple math because you slept for about 4 hours. The topic itself is possibly the easiest one from the book.

Comment: yes ! Don't forget: A freshly charged  average is better than a sleepy Einstein ;-)

Comment: Another alternative formulation of the linear estimator $$\boxed{ \hat{Y} = \rho_{xy} \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}(X-m_x) + m_y }$$ is to multiply numerator and denominator by $\sigma_x$ to get $$\boxed{ \hat{Y} =  \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\operatorname{var}(X)}(X-m_x) + m_y }$$ which can save some square-rooting or just calculation of $\rho_{xy}$ etc. In the question asked. Note that $\operatorname{var}(X)$ is given while $$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=\operatorname{cov}(Y+N,Y)=\operatorname{var}(Y)+\operatorname{cov}(N,Y),$$

Answer (score 1):

So in your case doesn't the relation $x = n+y$ help ?

I mean, assuming your derivation for the mean square estimtor is right, then to compute $E\{xn\}$ you would look for $E\{ (y+n)n\}$ and using properties of $x$ and $n$ you would get

$$E\{xn\} = E\{(y+n)n\} = E\{yn\} + E\{n^2\} = 0.5 + 1 = 1.5 $$

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Why is E(n^2) = 1? And the second problem is that a and b are given for a general solution y=ax+b. Reading again what I wrote I'm no longer sure if I have to substitute x with y+n or if have to substitute y with n-x in the formula.

Comment: you said variance of $n$ is $1$, and it's also zero-mean; so $Var\{n\} = E\{n^2\} - \mu_n^2 = E\{n^2\} = 1$

Comment: To your latter confusion, according to your statement (which is alitle confusing indeed) your **measurement** (observation) is $x$, and you want to **estimate** $y$ from $x$. the relation between the two is given by $n$.

Comment: and you could also use $E\{xn\} = E\{x(x-y)\} = E\{x^2\}-E\{xy\} = 3 - 1.5 = 1.5$.